# Download CSV file link with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, web-scraping

Im trying to programatically download this CSV link (https://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.csv?version=59fa0f4b59dfe70e557208f86ab2d2a0)
From this site https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar

-A short ways down Left hand side of site.

```
$source = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.csv?version=59fa0f4b59dfe70e557208f86ab2d2a0' 
    $Destination = "C:\filelocation\thisweek.csv"
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($source, $Destination)
```

Can anybody shed some light on what Im doing incorrectly here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. Use `-OutFile`: `Invoke-RestMethod 'https://nfs.faireconomy....../.....' -OutFile path\to\csv.csv`

Comment: You are combining two different things. Either use Invoke-WebRequest/RestMethod with -outfile or use the webclient.downloadfile method. Also, this has nothing to do with web scraping.

Comment: I was overcomplicating.  Thank you so much!